# php get only day and hours from an interval of two date

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

How can I calculate the differences between two dates in days and hours? For example, if:

- `date1` = 2015-03-05 09:25:00
- `date2` = 2015-03-09 11:25:03

The desired result is the difference between `date1` and `date2`, or:

- 4 days and 2 hours

I tried doing this:

```
$interval = date_diff($data_in, $data_out);
$days=$interval->days;
$hours=$interval->format('%h');
echo "days: ".$days. " hours: ".$hours;
```

The `$days` are correct, but not the `$hours`. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Comment: What incorrect result are you getting? This works as intended, using DateTime objects for the two dates. http://3v4l.org/fHKRC

Comment: Improved formatting and grammar

Comment: i resolved putting $interval->format('%h') in an array of hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using exactly this code, the output I get is "days 4 hours: 2":

```
<?php
  $data_in = new DateTime('2015-03-05 09:25:00');
  $data_out = new DateTime('2015-03-09 11:25:03');
  $interval = date_diff($data_in, $data_out);
  $days = $interval->days;
  $hours=$interval->format('%h');
  echo "days ".$days." hours: ".$hours;
?>
```

Can you post where you're getting $data_in and $data_out from?  In your "example" you use "date1" and "date2" and in your code you use $data_in and $data_out.  Could you verify that the timezones are the same and that the dates really contain what you're expecting by doing the following:

```
var_dump($data_in);
var_dump($data_out);
```

Comment: i resolved putting $interval->format('%h') in an array of $hours

Comment: OK.  I'm glad you found a solution!  :)